# How to Twirl, Whirl, Spiral in dimensions higher than 2D

Tags: c++, geometry, noise

I have some code like the following in C++:

```
for(int x = position.x; x < position.x + dimensions.x; ++x)
{
    for(int y = position.y; y < position.y + dimensions.y; ++y)
    {
        glm::vec2 tc = glm::vec2(x,y);
        tc -= spiralPosition;
        float distance = glm::length(tc-position);
        if(distance < spiralRadius)
        {
            float percent = (spiralRadius - distance) / spiralRadius;
            float theta = percent * percent * angle;
            float s = std::sin(theta);
            float c = std::cos(theta);
            tc = glm::vec2(glm::dot(tc,glm::vec2(c,-s)),glm::dot(tc,glm::vec2(s,c)));
        }
        tc += spiralPosition;
        returnValues[x][y] = noise->GetValue(tc);
    }
}
```

What it does, is produces a container of gradient noise values. While it does this, it also spirals the results around an epicentre, like a cyclone. It's based on the code here, results look identical:

http://www.geeks3d.com/20110428/shader-library-swirl-post-processing-filter-in-glsl/

What I'd like to do now is extend this into 3D, 4D, basically *n*D.

I'm not familiar with the trigonometry to understand what needs to be done. I have a thought that tangent is needed for the third dimensions, but then I'm lost on how to do a fourth dimension.

Can anyone point me to some articles that will help me understand, google isn't really helping me (but I'm honestly probably using the incorrect search terms).

Comment: Have a look at [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), and [n-spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged c++ but it's not clear what class library you're using for n-dimensional vector math, so I'll try to answer the question purely mathematically, assuming you have classes to represent N-dimensional vectors and NxN-dimensional matrices (i.e. linear mappings from N-dimensional euclidean space onto itself).

Generalizing your 2d code, the algorithm for computing the spiral mapping becomes something like:

1. Translate the center of the spiral to the origin ([vector subtraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations#Addition_and_multiplication_of_vectors)).
2. Get the distance of the point to be mapped from the origin (using the [N dimensional euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#n_dimensions)).
3. Compute a rotation angle based on that distance (`theta = percent * percent * angle;`)
4. Map the N-1-dimensional sphere centered on the origin at that radius onto itself by rotating around the center.
5. Translate the origin back to the center of the spiral.

Step 4 is likely where you are stuck. In generalizing (rotational) mappings to spheres of N-1 dimensions, one must keep in mind the [Hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), which states:

> There is no nonvanishing continuous tangent vector field on even-dimensional n-spheres.

What this means is that, for odd-dimensional vector spaces (i.e. even dimensional embedded spheres), there's always going to be at least one visible fixed point in your spiral mapping, and this *cannot be avoided*.  In your case, since you are using rotational mappings, there will be *two* fixed points, one each where your selected axis of rotation intersects the n-1-sphere.

Now, an n-dimensional spiral mapping between the first two dimensions in an n-dimensional euclidean space is going to look like (as an NxN linear transformation matrix):

```
    ⎡cos(θ)   −sin(θ)    0     .     0⎤
    ⎢sin(θ)    cos(θ)          .      ⎢
S = ⎢  0          0      1     .     0⎢
    ⎢  .          .      .     .      ⎢
    ⎣  0          0                  1⎦
```

One can then compose spiral transformations between subsequent pairs of axes to get the following NxN linear transformation matrix:

```
    ⎡cos(θ)   −sin(θ)     0         0                  ⎤
    ⎢sin(θ)    cos(θ)     0         0                  ⎢
    ⎢  0         0      cos(θ)   −sin(θ)               ⎢
S = ⎢  0         0      sin(θ)    cos(θ)               ⎢
    ⎢                                      .           ⎢
    ⎢                                            .     ⎢
    ⎣                                                 1⎦
```

Notice the trailing `1` in the final cell?  That's there when your N-dimensional space has an odd number of dimensions, and, thanks to the Hairy Ball theorem, can't be dispensed with.

In 3 dimensions, this becomes a spiral around the Z axis:

```
    ⎡cos(θ)   −sin(θ)      0⎤
S = ⎢sin(θ)    cos(θ)      0⎢
    ⎣   0         0        1⎦
```

Thus if `O` is the center of the spiral and `P` a point to transform, the overall transform would be:

```
newP = O + S(P - O)
```

If you would prefer to spiral around a different axis, you would construct a rotational matrix `R` taking that axis to the Z axis, then the overall spiral matrix would become `(R⁻¹)*S*R`. To create the rotation matrix `R`, see e.g. [Rotating one 3-vector to another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293116/rotating-one-3-vector-to-another).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the vector/matrix math is via GLM library. Have I got it right above that I will be multiplying my offset position by the `S` matrix above? What are the missing values in the matrices (I'm missing something)?

Comment: @DavidMurphy - those are all block-diagonal matrices, so all zeros in the upper left and lower right.  GLM only supports 2d and 3d vectors, right?  Its 4d vector is actually for colorspaces?

Comment: No, it fully support 4D vectors as far as I know. Yes, they're generally used for color, but you can do any regular vector math on them.